# Spring Kafka - Задержка времени у @KafkaListener при использовании seekToTimestamp у AbstractConsumerSeekAware

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, apache-kafka

Пытаюсь реализовать Rest API с использованием Kafka. POST запрос обрабатывается быстро очень быстро и никаких нареканий к нему нет. GET запрос отрабатывает не совсем корректно и с заметной задержкой времени.

Кусок лога от GET запроса:

```
'''
2021-09-21 17:08:17.651  INFO 204 --- [6.1-9001-exec-5] c.e.v.controller.FrameController         : FrameController: Получены данные из Kafka за последние 50 секунд: []
2021-09-21 17:08:22.192  INFO 204 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group_id-1, groupId=group_id] Seeking to offset 5648 for partition camera-0
2021-09-21 17:08:22.196  INFO 204 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer      : Kafka: Получен фрейм: Frame{name='frame0001.jpg', total=2, timestamp='2020-08-29 20:21:00', autonumbers=[аа001а34, аа001а34], url='http://192.168.56.103:9000/frames/21-09-2021/frame0001.jpg'}, metainfo: 1632233288747, camera, 5648, 0
2021-09-21 17:08:22.196  INFO 204 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer      : Kafka: Получен фрейм: Frame{name='frame0001.jpg', total=2, timestamp='2020-08-29 20:21:00', autonumbers=[аа001а34, аа001а34], url='http://192.168.56.103:9000/frames/21-09-2021/frame0001.jpg'}, metainfo: 1632233289829, camera, 5649, 0
2021-09-21 17:08:22.196  INFO 204 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer      : Kafka: Получен фрейм: Frame{name='frame0001.jpg', total=2, timestamp='2020-08-29 20:21:00', autonumbers=[аа001а34, аа001а34], url='http://192.168.56.103:9000/frames/21-09-2021/frame0001.jpg'}, metainfo: 1632233290937, camera, 5650, 0
2021-09-21 17:08:22.196  INFO 204 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer      : Kafka: Получен фрейм: Frame{name='frame0001.jpg', total=2, timestamp='2020-08-29 20:21:00', autonumbers=[аа001а34, аа001а34], url='http://192.168.56.103:9000/frames/21-09-2021/frame0001.jpg'}, metainfo: 1632233292091, camera, 5651, 0
'''
```

То есть, после того как через GET-запрос поступило время, на которое необходимо передвинуть offset, Listener понимает об этом только через 5 секунд (в данном случае, обычно время варьируется  и составляет от 2 до 5 секунд). Почему возникает данная задержка и есть ли возможность через GET-запрос получить данные из Kafka за время = текущее время - время от GET-запроса.

Буду очень благодарен, за консультацию! Заранее спасибо!

Часть кода, которая относится к Consumer и GET-запросу.

Исходный код:

Конфигурационный файл:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    private String groupId;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE, "com.example.videocamerarestapi.model.Frame");
        return configProps;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Frame> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Frame> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Frame> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Контроллер:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/frames")
public class FrameController {

    KafkaProducerService kafkaProducerService;
    KafkaConsumerService kafkaConsumerService;
    MinioService minioService;

    @Autowired
    public FrameController(KafkaProducerService kafkaProducerService, KafkaConsumerService kafkaConsumerService, MinioService minioService) {
        this.kafkaProducerService = kafkaProducerService;
        this.kafkaConsumerService = kafkaConsumerService;
        this.minioService = minioService;
    }

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FrameController.class);

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> addFrame(@RequestBody RequestFrame requestFrame)
    {
        Frame frame = new Frame();

        String name = requestFrame.getName();
        int total = requestFrame.getTotal();
        String timestamp = requestFrame.getTimestamp();
        String[] autonumbers = requestFrame.getAutonumbers();
        String base64 = requestFrame.getBase64();

        frame.setName(name);
        frame.setTotal(total);
        frame.setTimestamp(timestamp);
        frame.setAutonumbers(autonumbers);

        minioService.uploadFile(name, base64);

        String url = minioService.getUrl(name);

        frame.setUrl(url);

        kafkaProducerService.send("camera",frame);

        logger.info("FrameController: Новый фрейм был добавлен в MinIO и данные по нему переданы в Kafka: {}", frame);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Frame>> getFrame(@RequestParam int time)  {

        kafkaConsumerService.getDataInTime(time);

        List<Frame> frames = kafkaConsumerService.getFrames();

        logger.info("FrameController: Получены данные из Kafka за последние {} секунд: {}", time, frames);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(frames, HttpStatus.OK);

    }

}
```

Сервис:

```
@Service
public class KafkaConsumerService extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer.class);

    private List<Frame> frames = new ArrayList<>();

    @KafkaListener(topics = "camera")
    public List<Frame> consume(Frame frame, ConsumerRecordMetadata meta) {
        frames.add(frame);
        logger.info(String.format("Kafka: Получен фрейм: %s, metainfo: %d, %s, %d, %d", frame, meta.timestamp(), meta.topic(), meta.offset(), meta.partition()));
        return frames;

    }

    public void getDataInTime(long time) {
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() - time * 1000;
        seekToTimestamp(timestamp);
    }

    public List<Frame> getFrames() {
        return frames;
    }

}
```

Модели:

```
public class Frame {

    private String name;
    private int total;
    private String timestamp;
    private String[] autonumbers;
    private String url;

    public Frame() {
    }

    public Frame(String name, int total, String timestamp, String[] autonumbers, String url) {
        this.name = name;
        this.total = total;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.autonumbers = autonumbers;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Frame(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String[] getAutonumbers() {
        return autonumbers;
    }

    public void setAutonumbers(String[] autonumbers) {
        this.autonumbers = autonumbers;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Frame{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", total=" + total +
                ", timestamp='" + timestamp + '\'' +
                ", autonumbers=" + Arrays.toString(autonumbers) +
                ", url='" + url + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Настройки:

```
server.address = 192.168.56.1
server.port = 9001

spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers = 192.168.56.103:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id = group_id

spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers = 192.168.56.103:9092

minio.bucket.name=frames
minio.access.name=minio
minio.access.secret=miniostorage
minio.url=http://192.168.56.103:9000

spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=5MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

Настройки логгирования:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, STDOUT, file

log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=mylogs.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не то, как Кафка и ConsumerSeekAware должны использоваться.

Если тебе нужно получать данные запросом, как из базы данных, используй базу данных.

По проблеме - почитай, когда операция `seekToTimestamp` отрабатывает https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConsumerSeekAware.ConsumerSeekCallback.html#seekToTimestamp(java.lang.String,int,long)

Если ты её используешь не из двух мест, для которых она предназначена, то она ставится в очередь и исполняется только когда листенер будет делать commit offset (== после обработки полученного сообщения). Именно поэтому ты наблюдаешь нерегулярные задержки.